# Passing data through bundle

Tags: java, android, bundle

I want to send data which i do this way :

```
public static final String Itemmm = "tryIT";

String item3 = (String)arrayAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
ClassicsA class = new Classics();
Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
bundle2.putString(ClassicsB.Itemmm, item3);
class.setArguments(bundle2);
```

And to receive data I do this:

```
Bundle bundle2 = this.getArguments();

    if(bundle2!=null){
        String i = bundle2.getString(ClassicsB.Itemmm, "");
        testButton.setText(i);
    }
```

However the data is never being sent, when I check the value of testButton it's empty. Can you see what i am doing wrong? When I add item3 between the brackets it just takes the item3 as a string.

BTW this is communication between 2 fragments.

Answer (score 0):

To **Send** the data, use the following lines of code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY", "VALUE");

// set Fragmentclass Arguments 
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And in order to **recieve** a data use this:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("KEY");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Hope this helps.